# I have a logical error code and I can not find

Tags: java

I have a logical error code and I can not find out where it would be happy to solve the code

```
public static int nameCheck(char[] names) {
    int blankCount = 0;
    for (int i = names.length; i > 1; i--) {
        if (names[i - 1] == ' ') {
            blankCount++;
        }
    }
    return blankCount;
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and post a [mcve].  How are we supposed to know what this is supposed to do?

Comment: Iterating backwards over the array and then subtracting one from the index makes this very difficult to read. However, I think the issue might be that the loop condition should be `>=1`.

Answer (score 1):

When a for loop 'loops', java *first* executes the 'incrementor' expression (here, `i--`), and *then* checks the condition (here, `i > 1`), and will abort the loop then and tehre if the condition no longer holds.

Thus, eventually i is 2, you check `names[i - 1]` (and java is 0-indexed, so `names[1]` returns the **second character**). Then, i is decremented to 1, **and the loop ends**.

Thus, this code fails to count the first character if it is blank.

Simply make that `i > 0` to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually writing your loop wrongly.
Perhaps your question isn't clear enough

It should be this way i guess.

```
public static int nameCheck(char[] names){ int blankCount = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i > names.length; i--) {
  if (names[i-1] == ' ') {
        blankCount++;
}        
}
return blankCount;
}
```